# wordpress seeing 404 but the files exist?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

So my site is loading VERY slowly so I checked it on gtmetrix.com. The results, below, show that several JS files don't exist.

I have manually checked via FTP, the files ARE there. When I check in my browser directly, wordpress gives me the 404 page.

Is this a .htaccess problem? I really don't get it.

https://gtmetrix.com/reports/gonzalezfurniture.net/t6Exkx0i

edit:

below is the htaccess rule:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Could the problem be that first line after rewriteBase, stopping all other rules?

Comment: sounds like a permissions error on the server

Comment: Im checking permissions on the folders, but let me add new info. I saw something in the htaccess file that might be doing it but thats not my strong suite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, the child folders inside the plugins folder had various permissions set, which prevented some plugins or specific plugin files from loading.